# Migrating data from RDBMS to Arango DB: Bulk upload

Tags: api, rdbms, arangodb

Iam trying to move data from RDBMS to ArangoDB. I wanted to know if there are any tools for transforming the RDBMS data to collections and edges to do a bulk upload to ArangoDB. I could also see that ArangoDB bulk upload API allows only one type of collection to be uploaded at a time. Is there anyway to upload collections and edges at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to upload both at the same time would be to run multiple instances of your import program/script (e.g. arangoimport or JavaScript/Python/PowersHell script).  But realistically, there aren't many situations when you ***need*** to do this simultaneously, and attempting to do so might cause problems).

As for data transformation, that is a different topic, and the answer depends wholly on your level of comfort with various technologies.  Personally, I use several tools but mainly rely on Pentaho Data Integration ([info](https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Latest+Pentaho+Data+Integration+%28aka+Kettle%29+Documentation) and [download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/?source=navbar)) to export data and JS and Python scripts to import, leveraging the ArangoDB API.

Because DB platform transition is ***SO*** individualized, you won't find a tool to quickly do this, especially when you're moving from RDBMS to document/graph.  Normalization requirements between the two can be quite different, usually requiring you to re-work the data model.